# How to display a large amount of data in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to show a large amount of data  in gridview but the problem is that everytime data increase the  gridview row size increase automatically.
is there any possible way that the data which is stored in my  MS access Database  display in multi line instead of one single long line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are populating the GridView using `AutoGenerate="true"` make if `AutoGenerate="false"`

Then use `asp:TemplateField` to populate the GridView.
Now give an `ItemStyle-Width` and `ItemStyle-Wrap`.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="ShipNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShipName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand your question fully but it sounds as a Repeater might work better for you where you have more control of the layout of the rendering.

If it is the amount of rows that are the problem I do recommend to introduce paging to limit amount of row displayed at once.

**Update:**

1) Set up a CssClass for the GridView itself and include the table-layout:fixed style. This tells the browser that you're going to specify the width of each cell. You may also want to include the overall width of the grid here as I mention in (3).

2) The first row of the table sets the width for each cell, and that's usually the HEADER row, not the item row, so use either HeaderStyle-CssClass or HeaderStyle-Width to set the width of the cell.

3) Make certain the table itself is wide enough to hold all of the cells. I added up all of my cell widths and used that to set the width via the CssClass attribute on the GridView.

Comment: actually in  have three column one is name one is  details and one is ID  ,  In  details column i  put a long detail.  like  this message. but  it shows all the data in one single row. i want to distribute that  long text into multi lines.

Answer (score 0):

The telerik gridview control supports multi line rows http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx.

However, this does cost. You may try displaying only a few columns, then the user has to click on the row to see the other information in a form view.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns='false'>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField='Name' />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat='server' ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="None"
                        TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'
                        >
                    </asp:TextBox>        
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

You may have to add some styling to gridview via .skin or css